# Upload file using FormData and jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery

I tried to follow some examples from stackoverflow and a few blogs.
But I can't get a file uploaded.

I have a form like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" id="viewport" name="viewport" value="1">

  <input type="hidden" id="idinfo" name="idinfo" value="-1">

  <input type="file" id="filename" name="filename" value="">

  <select id="cbTipe" name="cbTipe" onchange="ChangeType()">
    <option value="1">Text</option>
    <option value="2">Text &amp; Foto</option>
    <option value="8">Video</option>
  </select>

  <button type="button" name="btnClear" onclick="ClearForm();">Bersihkan Form</button>
  <button type="button" name="btnSimpan" onclick="SubmitForm();">Simpan</button>

</form>
```

And JavaScript code like this:

```
function SubmitForm()
{
  data = $("form input").serialize();

  aFormData = new FormData($("form *"));

  aFormData.append("filename", data[2]);

  $("form input").each(
    function(i)
    {
      aFormData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this).attr("value"));
    }
  );

  $("form select").each(
    function(i)
    {
      aFormData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this).attr("value"));
    }
  );

  $.ajax(
    {
      url         : the_url + "/form_action",
      type        : "POST",
      contentType : false,
      processData : false,
      data        : aFormData,
      dataType    : "json",
      success     : 
        function(data)
        {
          if(data['status'] == 'ok')
          {
            RefreshList(data['html'])
          }
          else
          {
            alert("Error on FormAction")
          }

          ClearForm();
       }
    }
  );
}
```

And a Grails code like this:

```
def test = request.getFile('filename').getName()
```

The problem is, I always fail to get

```
request.getFile('filename').getName()
```

request.getFile('filename') returns null.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

FormData takes the dom reference as the argument, not jQuery wrapper.

So try

```
aFormData = new FormData($("form").get(0));
```

also

```
aFormData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this).val());
```

to get the value of an input you need to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) not [.attr('value')](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Also to append the file you need to add the file reference like

```
aFormData.append("filename", $('#filename').get(0).files[0]);
```

So your code might have to look like

```
function SubmitForm() {
    var aFormData = new FormData();

    aFormData.append("filename", $('#filename').get(0).files[0]);

    $("form input").each(function(i) {
        aFormData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this).val());
    });

    $("form select").each(function(i) {
        aFormData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this).val());
    });

    ......
}
```

Comment: Arun, I can upload the file if the webapp is deployed on windows. But it failed when the webapp deployed on ubuntu. Should it be treated differently?

Comment: not really... but I don't have any experience in grails... so can't comment on that... as far as client code is considered it, the server really should not matter

Comment: I kept a log for both deployments. On windows deployment, the 'request' is a 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' object. While on ubuntu deployment, the 'request' is a 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest' object. What does it mean?

Comment: do you have commons fileupload library in the classpath

Comment: probably if you can ask a different question, with spring and grails tags then somebody who have better experience in that could help you better

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33408/discussion-between-fasisi-and-arun-p-johny)

Comment: let's continue the discussion on different thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628417/different-classes-grails-use-to-handle-upload-files)