# Different classes grails use to handle upload files

Tags: grails

I have a grails controller which handle fileupload.
I deployed the application on glassfish in windows and in ubuntu.

On windows deployment, the request object of

```
request.getFile("filename")
```

is of type commons.CommonsMultipartFile

while on ubuntu deployment the request is of type support.DefaultMultipart

What causes this different behavour?
Is there a way to make it consistent?

The application server is glassfish3.1.2

Comment: are you using the same browser in both cases?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the second class, are you sure it is `support.DefaultMultipart`?

Answer (score 0):

Anything grails supplies via the `request.getFile(...)` method should implement the Spring `MultipartFile` interface. As long as you stick to the methods available in the interface, you shouldn't need to worry about what concrete implementation you receive.

Answer (score 0):

the problem solved after I upgraded the glassfish from 3.1.2 to glassfish 4 in windows and ubuntu.

there may be some other ways to solve this. but i solved this by upgrading the glassfish.